# Custom Permissions in Django with Problematic Model

Tags: python, django, authorization

My current project involves a legacy codebase which makes use of Django's models in a limited way; `syncdb` isn't being used (i.e., the model is not Django-managed).  I need to restrict access to certain columns based on permissions (i.e. a view_all permission will show all of the columns, while no permission will restrict the user to a few basic columns).  This permission will apply to different tables.

The way I am thinking of doing this is to simply use SQL to insert a new `auth_permission`.  However, this is complicated by the `content_type_id` column: my understanding is that a content type applies to *one* model, and this (as I said) will need to apply to different tables, and I can't reliably run `syncdb`.

Has anyone else implemented something along these lines?  Did you use the Django infrastructure, or did you end up using a separate table for safety?  Did you implement this at the signal level, or at each point where the model is used?

Thanks!

Comment: are you going to use this functionality just in one view?

Comment: do you want to be able to restrict access to any combination of columns or are there just a view user groups like this for example: one group should see all columns, another group should see half the columns and yet another group should see only two columns

Comment: My project is a set of web services and will need to restrict the columns in every API where they're used.  The columns that are restricted will be the same throughout:  one group can see all columns, another group can see only a sub-set.

Comment: What version of django are you running? Why can't you use django permissions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-permission-required-decorator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are actually looking for permission groups. They can be easily created model independently. The user groups wouldn't need to contain any actual permissions.

You can check if a user is in a specific group:

```
def user_in_group(user, group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).count()
```

You could use it like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    if user_in_group(request.user, 'view_all'):
        # do the things
    else:
        # do the other things

# limit this view to 'view_all' users
@user_passes_test(lambda u: user_in_group(u, 'view_all'))
def my_other_view(request):
    # and do some more things
```

I don't know what you mean with

> Did you implement this at the signal level, or at each point where the
>   model is used?

Obviously with any authorization method you would need to insert checks wherever a model is viewed and insert logic to show only the permitted columns (like rendering a subset of columns in a template).

To make sure that no wrong columns are accessed you could write proxy classes that limit access to the apropriate fields/columns and use proxy instances instead of model instances.

```
class SomeModelProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, model_instance, user):
        self.instance = model_instance
        self.user = user

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.save(*args, **kwargs)

    # define other methods that are needed...

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if not name in get_allowed_columns_for_user_somehow(self.user):
            raise AttributeError

        return getattr(self.instance, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if not name in get_allowed_columns_for_user_somehow(self.user):
            raise AttributeError

        setattr(self.instance, name, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always create custom permissions around a dummy object, i.e.:

```
class ColumnLevelPermissions(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
             ("can_view_column1", "Can view column 1"),
             ("can_view_column2", "Can view column 2"),
        )
```

then create a wrapper to filter your database call(you say your models are not managed by Django models.Model):

```
class SelectManager(object):
    def get_columns(user):
        allowed_columns = []
        if user.has_perm('app.can_view_column1'):
            allowed_columns.append('column1')
        return allowed_columns
```

The only thing to decide is how to use this. You can create your objects from Database as dict(), and just to filter the columns in the object by key if appear in allowed_columns.
This will mean that you will however read some redundant data from the database. Another solution is to modify the "Select " query, based on the columns, although this is not so secure approach.

Some more info on how the objects are stored and read in the code could be useful for defining the best approach.

Comment: Let me rephrase:  they are managed by Django, in that ORM classes are used to query the db, but the schema cannot be built by Django and syncdb is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#id9) can help you. I've never used it but i think you may use it.

You can [create some permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#programmatically-creating-permissions) for a group of users and then show some columns or others depending on who is requesting that page/template (with a simple "if" template tag). It can be a little tedious, but it could help you to acomplish what you are looking for.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, the brute force method is what I've landed on myself... we're using lxml rather than Django templates, however.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to show all/partial objects for any table, depending on some property of the user/consumer. A user won't have partial access to some rows and full access to other rows, it's a all-or-nothing.

This has nothing to do with the ContentTypes frameworks, which allows polymorphic relationships at the *row* level. You just need to filter the exposed fields in the view.

If you use the standard user/group classes, you can add a permission for each table, "see_complete_xxx", and assign groups, then in the view (which being an api will probably loop over the fields and convert them to json/xml/whatever) serialize only the allowed fields for the group.

Something in the line of:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class MyModel(models.Model):

    def serialize_full(self):
        return model_to_dict(self)

    def serialize_restricted(self):
        return model_to_dict(self, self.low_level_access_fields)

    def serialize_to_dict(self, user):
        if self.user_can_view_all(user):
            return self.serialize_full
        else:
            return self.serialize_restricted

    @classmethod
    def user_can_view_all(cls, user)
        return user.has_perm('my_model.see_all')

    @classmethod
    def low_level_access_fields(cls)
        return ["id", "name", "nickname"]
```

And you can extract most of this code into a mixin and use it where needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's partial; so, one field on object A and another field on object B might be restricted.  This is at least as related to bad data modeling as it is to a real technical problem.

Comment: I understand, but for a given model class B, is the set of "available fields to a restricted user" the same for **every** record of class B, and are all the records of B "available" or "restricted" depending only on the user? Can a user have full access on a specific record of B and partial access on another record of B?

Comment: The former is true; the second and third are true, because only fields of B will be restricted (i.e. all records visible, some fields restricted on each).